# How to call a function asynchronously in Flask?

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, flask, multiprocessing

I have a Python Flask REST API that takes in an image, and applies some image processing using [PIL](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/), [OpenCV](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) & [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf).

Let's call this function `image_processing`. I need to rotate this image four times (angles 0, 90, 180 and 270) and apply the function `image_processing` in each of them. Currently I am doing it sequentially, but I want to process them in parallel in order to reduce the time taken. I have tried using Python multi-threading and multi-processing, but have come into the following problems.

1. **Problem with Python Multiprocessing** - Here, all the libraries (tensorflow, opencv, PIL etc.) are loaded for every worker which results in the system memory being choked out (one process takes about 1.5GB or RAM)
2. **Problem with Python Multithreading** - Thread locking is happening here. The Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) allows only one thread to run Python code at a time, resulting in the same time as it takes to do the process sequentially.

What can I do to achieve this concurrency?

Comment: The main problem with threads is not resources; it is the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) which allows only one thread to run Python code at a time. If your operation is computing heavy (i.e. runs Python bytecode for most of the time) you are better off with multiprocessing as you have already experienced the wrath of the GIL. Is adding more RAM an option?

Comment: @Selcuk No, adding more RAM would not be an option. Do you think libraries like asyncio, celery etc. can be used in any way?

Answer (score 1):

You can try out the celery-flask combination.
As mentioned in the docs, Celery is an asynchronous task queue/job queue based on distributed message passing.

Please check the link below to start out with celery. As you are already using flask you would only have to go through the docs and integrate celery with flask.
[Celery-based-background-tasks](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/0.12.x/patterns/celery/#running-the-celery-worker)

Comment: What I understand and as written in the documentation 'If your application has a long running task, such as processing some uploaded data or sending email, you don’t want to wait for it to finish during a request' is that, you can give task to the celery workers without having the request-response loop wait for it. But here, I need to wait for the 4 parallel tasks to complete before proceeding further. Does celery help with that?

Comment: You will have to use some database like Redis. Simple way would be to update the redis counter key when one worker is done executing. When all the workers are done you can proceed further.

Comment: That won't make the process finish faster though.